# can i write a similar class as "System" for printing something?

Tags: java, println, system.out

can i  build a user-defined class for printing anything using printstream variable just as  "System" class ?

so what i did is:

```
    import java.io.*;

    public final class SystemDemo{



public final static InputStream give=null;//the same variables 

public final static PrintStream take=null;

public final static PrintStream error = null;

}
```

and  wanted to use this SystemDemo class  as "System"(pre-defined)
,like

```
    SystemDemo.take.println("something");
```

but i get a NullPointerException .

Comment: You are setting variables as `null`, *and* you're getting NPE? That's *almost* impossible. ;) Just kidding...

Comment: just as in System class declaration @zlakad

Comment: Ummm.. you set it to null?

Comment: The System class declaration uses some clever magic to initialize the `in` and `out` and `err` streams.  You don't want to do that.  (Not least because it probably won't work reliably.  The `System` class gets special support from the JIT compiler to make it work properly.)

Comment: @MartinJames - i did just as in "System" class declaration

Comment: SHould you not have an initialization block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, will work same for your requirement,

```
 public final class SystemDemo
 {
    public final static PrintStream take =  new PrintStream(System.out);
 }
```

And then use this as,

```
SystemDemo.take.println("Your String");
```

It worked fine, tested with Netbeans.

Comment: thanks @mrunmay-deswandikar

Comment: Yea.  This is the part that you can do safely.  The part that you can't do is emulate the behavior of `System.setIn()` etcetera and the "magic" that `System` uses to *actually* initialize the `final` variables.  Using nasty reflection or `Unsafe` is not guaranteed to work reliably for modifying `final` variables.

Comment: Right, the main part is we can't get from API, how the out object is internally initialized, if we try to initialize, any custom Out object, we can't manage it. Java internally handles this.